# kinect V2 get real xyz points from raw depth image in matlab without visionKinectDepthToSkeleton or depthToPointCloud or pcfromkinect

Tags: matlab, kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect, kinect-v2

There are many ways to get real xyz from raw depth image like  vision.internal.visionKinectDepthToSkeleton or depthToPointCloud or pcfromkinect .
The problem is that it's not clear how these functions work exactly . All these functions use vision.internal.visionKinectDepthToSkeleton and visionKinectDepthToSkeleton is a .p file and encrypted .
Why I want to know how do they work ? Cause I want to write an Inverse function for them that get the xyz points and convert it to 424*512 depth image. 
In kinect V1 , there is a clear formula for converting raw depth image data to xyz but I couldn't find any working solution for kinect V2.
It's better for me working in matlab environment but feel free using anything you want.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

I have the following code which does the job. It reads the depth image and converts into X,Y,Z values. I might have got it from the "[libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2)" forum. As far as the intrinsic parameters are concerned, you could use the values that I have been using or get you own using the [calibration toolbox](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/) along with a checker board pattern.

```
function [Xw, Yw, Zw] = Depth2World_v2(fileName, maxDepth)
% Extrinsic parameters of the depth camera. These values are collected
%from the dicussion forum.
fx=367.286994337726;        % Focal length in X and Y
fy=367.286855347968;
cx=255.165695200749;        % Principle point in X and Y
cy=211.824600345805;
k1=0.0914203770220268;
k2=-0.269349746097515;
k3=0.0925671408453617;
p1=0;
p2=0;

% Read the depth image:
% Ex: fileName = 'depthImg_0018.ppm';
imgPixels = imread(fileName);
% imgPixels = imgPixels (:, end:-1:1);
x3D = zeros(size(imgPixels));
y3D = zeros(size(imgPixels));
z3D = zeros(size(imgPixels));

% Evaluate coordinates from depth image:
[maxR, maxC] = size(imgPixels);
for r=1:maxR
    for c=1:maxC
        % The depth value is equal to intensity. But it is stored in mm.
        d = double(imgPixels(r,c)) / 1000;
        z3D(r,c) = d;
        x3D(r,c) = (c - cx) * z3D(r,c) / fx;
        y3D(r,c) = (r - cy) * z3D(r,c) / fy;
    end
end
```

Here is a [link](http://blog.elonliu.com/2017/03/18/kinect-coordinate-mapping-summary-and-pitfalls/) explaining the camera model based on which the above equations are derived for X, Y and Z.